# How to compute the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{r}b^{2^i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the sum:

$$
S_r = b^1+b^2+b^4+\ldots + b^{2^{r-1}}+b^{2^r}
$$

I would like to find a formula for $S_r$ so that I can compute it without calculating each summand. Is it possible and if it is, what is the formula?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no closed form. You do get $S_n(b)=b+S_{n-1}(b^2)$.

Comment: closest I can get is an estimation of it's value mod 8 I think.